# How to use a decorator of class method

Tags: python, python-decorators

When I design a class, I wrote a class member function as a decorator

```
    def switchWindow(self, win: str):
        def actual_decorator(func):
            self.browser.switch_to.window(self.windowsHandles[win])

            def inner():
                func()
            return inner
        return actual_decorator
```

the decorator is used to change the eviroment for other member function before they're running, however, when I used the decorator over a member function like this:

```
    @switchWindow(win="crop")
    def test_cropFunction(self):
        pass
```

the IDE raised an error like this:

```
    @switchWindow(win="crop") TypeError: switchWindow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm confused by the error, but then I rewrote the decorator by add a 'self' before the decorator, but it's also wrong:

```
    @self.switchWindow(win="crop") NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: At the time you’re calling the decorator, `self` doesn’t exist yet. It makes no sense for the decorator to accept `self`, only `inner` would get a `self`. Hence it also makes little sense to write the decorator as a class member.

Comment: so should I make inner to accept 'self' and execute that sentence in the inner function?

Comment: You want to execute it when you call `test_cropFunction()`, right? Everything outside `inner` is happening at decorating time, which is too early.

Answer (score 0):

I move the decorator function out of the class, and make some changes like this:

```
def switchWindow(win: str):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        print(win)

        def inner(self):
            self.browser.switch_to.window(self.windowsHandles[win])
            func(self)
        return inner
    return actual_decorator
```

and now it works!